# Run loop on a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a list of n countries and a macro xyz. I want to create a new macro such that it selects country 1 and runs macro xyz, then country 2 and runs macro xyz,,,, till country n. How do I do this?

Comment: add a country argument to your macro xyz, and then do a `For Each...Next.  `Something like For Each country run this macro next country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are storing your "list of n countries".
Assuming from the title you have your countries in a range of cells (in column `col` equal to `1`, rows from `1` to `n` equal to 100; you would later adapt this),
something like this should work (I am under Ubuntu now and I cannot test it)

```
Option Explicit

Dim i as Integer, n as integer, col as Integer, 
Dim c as String

n = 100
col = 1
'Dim r as Range
For i = 1 To n
    c = Cells(i,col).Value
    Call xyz(c)
Next i
```

PS: I had just posted this answer assuming the countries were stored in an array of strings. Now I changed this as per the title.

Answer (score 1):

Well, few things with your "design": don't select anything! If you want to alter or do any operations on cell value, use `Cells.Value` property! Haing said that, modify your macro `xyz` to take one string argument:

```
Sub xyz(country As String)
```

If you want to alter a cell itself, you could do:

```
Sub xyz(countryCell As Range)
```

Now, if you want to loop through range, `For Each` loop might come in handy:

```
Sub FinalMacro()
Dim rng As Ragne, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A100") 'example range - enter the range conatining countries

For Each cell In rng
    Call xyz(cell.Value)
    'or Call xyz(cell)
Next
End Sub
```